# fstream -> seekp()/tellp() won't work

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a little problem with seekp() in fstream, whenever I want to set the position to X tellp return -1.

Code:

```
fstream file("Riot.exe", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::out);
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

...

if (...)
{ 
    long pos;
    file.seekp(882444);
    pos = file.tellp();
    std::cout << pos << std::endl; // pos = -1 
}
```

The result is, that `pos` return -1, what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked that you have opened the file?

Comment: Uhm, I've done this above the if-query, but I will try it, thank you.

Comment: @EdHeal Yes I've done this, but it won't work...

Comment: Are you sure there is a real position `882444`? If so, how do you know?

Comment: I don't think you can use seekp to extend the length of a file.  So, if the file is shorter than 882,444 bytes, the seekp fails, leaving the file with the fail bit set, and the tellp operation returns -1 because of the fail bit.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy the File is 1048576 Bytes big, and I want to write at position 882,444, so I have to set the put pointer to 882,444.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I've used file.seekg(0,ios::end) and file.tellg() that works lol

Comment: @NilsHickmann Okay, I'll add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To seek to the end of the file, set the relative position to 0 and the base position to `ios::end`:

```
if (...)
{ 
    std::streampos pos;
    file.seekp(0, ios::end);                                                   /*
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                    */
    pos = file.tellp();
    std::cout << pos << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: I thought you said it worked for you... Does `tellg` still return -1?

Comment: Yes but not there lol, yea it still return -1, if you want to have a look at the full program, here: http://pastebin.com/d4rrPjty

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, I've changed it to the value where I want to write. (new version: http://pastebin.com/Fi5Bwy07)

Comment: I would be very pleased if you could fix my problem :/, if not, thank you for your try. :)

Comment: @NilsHickmann I'm afraid I can't, sorry. You should ask again in more detail.

Comment: Ok, i've found the solution :DD I don't know why, but I have to put the code in a external function wich is not in the main(), thank you for your attempt to help me!! keep doing this! :) (here: http://pastebin.com/QU2ApzQT)